# When can I omit curly braces for a Ruby hash?

Tags: ruby

So this is legal in Ruby:

```
puts key: "value"
```

> {:key=>"value"}

But this is not:

```
hsh = key: "value"
puts hsh
```

> sandbox.rb:1: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting end-of-input
>
> hsh = key: "value"

**Why not?** When am I allowed to omit curly braces for hashes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can omit braces when a hash is the last argument of a method call. When you write:

```
 puts key: 'value'
```

you actually call the `puts` method with a param of `{key: value}`, so you can write:

```
puts({key: 'value'})
```

but in Ruby you can skip both normal and curly braces.

To see how it works in detail, consider these examples:

```
# Hash as only paramter
puts(a:1)
#{:a=>1}

# Hash as a last parameter
puts('cat', a: 1)
#cat
#{:a=>1}

# Hash as a first parameter - cannot skip
puts(a: 1, 'cat')
# >> SyntaxError: unexpected ')', expecting =>
# >> puts(a: 1, 'cat')
                ^
puts({a: 1}, 'cat')
#{:a=>1}
#cat

# Two hashes
puts({a: 1}, {b: 2})
#{:a=>1}
#{:b=>2}

puts({a: 1}, b: 2)
#{:a=>1}
#{:b=>2}
```

Comment: Is this the *only* time I can omit the curly braces? I've also seen the convention that you can omit the curly braces **when its the last parameter to a function call.** What about when it's not?

Comment: I don't recall any other case when you can write `key: 'value'` instead of `{key: 'value'}`. Do you have some troubling example in mind?

Comment: Ruby allows only the last parameter's braces to be omitted (see my answer). If you try it with a parameter that has another parameter after it, it'll fail because Ruby can't cope - it has to make some assumptions, after all.

Comment: Updated according to those suggesions.

Comment: Not in the context provided but technically speaking `instance.attribute=` is a method call but you cannot omit the braces in this case either.

Answer (score 3):

You can omit the braces when a hash is the last argument being passed to a function. So, you don't need them for options in a Rails `link_to` helper, for example, but you do need them in your `hsh = key: "value"` example because there's no function for the hash to be an argument of.